# How to fix re.sub capturing in Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am cleaning some data for text analysis that I extracted from PDFs. I have noticed that one of the errors is strange spacing in words that end in "y." Specifically, the final y is broken off from the word by a space: `theor y`. I'm trying to use `re.sub` to identify these instances and then collapse the space.

I've been able to write what I think is a good regex string (see https://regex101.com/r/M1jpe6/5), but I'm not getting the results that I expect. I suspect that I'm missing something about the `re.sub` method.

Here is my toy code.

```
import re
string = 'this is my theor y of dance'
regex_y = r'\b\w*\b(\sy)\b'

new_string = re.sub(regex_y, 'y', string)
print(new_string)
```

What I expect to print from the above is

`this is my theory of dance`

but what it actually prints is

`this is my y of dance`

Since the only capturing group in my regex is `(\sy)`, I expect to substitute `y` with `y`. Instead, it's clear that I'm matching on the bigger string `theor y` and then replacing that whole thing with `y`.

Why is this happening when I'm only capturing `(\sy)`? How do I write my `re.sub` string so it works as I intend?

Comment: you are capturing the whole word. Instead, capture only ` y` and replace it with `y`. you can use `\s+y` as your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a bit contrived, but if you wanted to remove whitespace before dangling `y` characters, I would use this:

```
string = 'this is my theor y of dance'
string = re.sub(r'\b\s+y\b', 'y', string)
print(string)

this is my theory of dance
```

The problem with using capture groups here is that you want to display the entire input sentence, with some modifications.  With a capture group approach, you would need to match and capture the entire string.

Comment: That definitely works and I can see why: it looks for a word boundary, followed by a `\s` character followed by a `y` and then replaces it all with just the `y`. Is there a reason (besides being simple and more direct) that I would not use a capturing group?

Comment: If you had given a more extensive example, I might have given a different answer.

Comment: Presumably you want a `\b` *after* the `y` as well, so you don't combine `"all of you"` into `"all ofyou"`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You're right +1.  Is it even possible write code correctly the first time on this site?